# Can we make N+1 block as a genesis block by deleting orignal genesis block?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bitcoin

I want to know that can we delete the genesis block and make the next block as the genesis block as it can save lot's of space and it can be used everywhere in all kinds of industry.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, in the blockchain, there is no way of deleting old blocks because immutability is one of the core properties. If you change one block 
 then all other blocks become invalid.

But if you still want to do then it is described here in another answer at Bitcoin exchange - 
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/53029/52106

Please take a look and hope this helps.